# Using socket.io inside my namespace

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, socket.io

I'm shipping socket.io as part of my code for 3rd party sites to use. I don't want it to pollute the global namespace (e.g. different versions of io will collide) but rather make it work only as part of my library, So it will be namespaced and called only from

`MyLibrary.io`

How do I go about this?

Comment: Can you control how this is all loaded? If you are shipping Socket.io with your code, then why don't you just change the variable it uses so it doesn't conflict?

Comment: I think you helped me solve this. Post this as an answer and get some points. I've used MyLib.prototype.io = {} on the first part of the script, followed by MyLib.prototype.io (and sometimes MyLib.prototype.io.Transport was needed)

Comment: Cool. I added my answer. Let me know if you have any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have total control over the file, then the easiest thing to do would be to just modify the file to load socket.io at a new location.

The easiest way I would say to do that would be to wrap the contents of `dist/socket.io.js` with

```
(function() {
  // All Standard SocketIO code

}).call(MyLibrary);
```

That will make the file load `io` onto `MyLibrary` instead. SocketIO, like many libraries, uses `this` to decide how to load things. In a browser circumstance, `this` is the object `window`, but by wrapping a function around everything, you can control `this` and change it to your own value by using the method `call`.

Many other libraries, though not socketIO, have a helper to avoid exactly this problem. Often they have a method called `noConflict()`. For example, if you wanted to avoid a problem like this for jQuery, you could do:

```
MyLibrary.$ = MyLibrary.jQuery = jQuery.noConflict(true);
```

That works because when jQuery loads, it saves a reference to the previously loaded version, so that if it needs to, it can set the global objects back to how they were.

Comment: What about the JSONP "io.j" callback ?  Doesn't that require you to have `io` on the `window` object ?

Comment: I can't say for `socket.io` specifically, but generally you add a randomly-named function to the window when dispatching a JSONP call, which is unrelated to the `io` object itself.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the suggested way to do this ([Issue #85](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client/issues/85)) is to load it as per normal then run these two lines:

```
MyLibrary.io = window.io; // Assign it to your desired namespace
delete window.io; // Remove it from the window namespace
```

The code in `socket.io.js` *only* adds the `io` variable to the `window`.

You could modify the code in `socket.io.js` but that might make it hard to maintain in the future since you would have to track changes you make to that file and propagate them into newer versions of `socket.io.js`.

At first, I thought you could do something with `module.exports` since it had the [CommonJS](http://www.commonjs.org/) format, however, after reading the code, I realized it's just the way things were organized before building the `socket.io.js` file. See the [file directory here](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client/tree/master/lib) for what I'm referring to.

Comment: This way means that when I load my version of socket.io either I'll overload the site's version or (worse) he will overload mine, and either way I'll delete the version he uses. I've just changed the source for socket.io with MyLib.prototype.io = {} as I wrote above

Comment: Yes, that's the other way. But I was trying to avoid modifying the file.